# How to unwrap text from a span in text block?

Tags: javascript

So i have big `<div>` block with text in it.
And word user double-clicks on is wrapping in `<span>` element
How can i delete that span element and return word to it's normal place, w/o span wrapping it, so whole text will return to starting position?

EDIT: 
Sorry for my absence.
Here's the code of double-click function
It wraps div, user have double clicked on in span and then adds class to that span. 
Looking like that!

```
function onDoubleClick(){
    var selection=window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var selectedText=selection.extractContents();
    var span=document.createElement("span");
    epic.get(span).addClass('highlightedText');
    span.appendChild(selectedText);
    selection.insertNode(span);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Code please? It's not exactly clear what you are aiming for.

Comment: Updated topic with code and screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you want, but I expect evil 'regex in HTML'-links in the comments :P. It's also dependent on the fact if the `<div>` only has text and spans in it or also many other (sub)children Dom-Nodes.

```
var html = $('#myDiv').html();
var new_html = html.replace(new RegExp('<span>[uU]ser</span>','gm'),'user');
$('#myDiv').html(new_html);
```

If you update the question I can give you a more precise answer to narrow down the collisions that can happen with RegEx.

Comment: That would remove all bindings that lived into #myDiv.. Probably not ideal