# Unwrap text from a span without regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `article` element where some portions of the text are wrapped by `span`s. E.g.

```
<article contenteditable="true">
    alice <span class="foo">bob</span> eve <span class="foo">bob</span>"
</article>
```

I'd like to replace a specific `span` element (e.g. the first) with its inner text, so the final result will be:

```
<article contenteditable="true">
    alice bob eve <span class="foo">bob</span>"
</article>
```

Please don't suggest to [replace all spans with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603786/how-to-unwrap-text-from-a-span-in-text-block) since I'd like to keep the second one. I do have the required `span` element saved in a variable, e.g. `mySpan`. Note that it's not necessarily the first span. E.g. if `mySpan` points to the second `span` element, the result should be:

```
<article contenteditable="true">
    alice <span class="foo">bob</span> eve bob"
</article>
```

Update: feel free to suggest `jquery` based solutions, since I'm using it anyway for other functions.

Comment: with regex you can also only update first occurence

Comment: It's not necessarily the first.

Comment: so. state your question clear :) youre questin says and i quote "I'd like to replace the first span"

Comment: Thanks, edited now.

Comment: "specific span element (e.g. the first)" and "Note that it's not necessarily the first span." - can you explain what you want exactly?

Comment: @Mark It could be the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. In the example it's the first one.

Comment: @dimid how do you think program must understand what exactly span should be replaced? so we need to see your `myspan` solution to move on

Comment: @Mark Please assume you already have `mySpan`, the specifics aren't important.

Comment: @dimid And how `myspan` value look like? it's interger number?

Comment: @Mark, no, it's the element itself. Anyhow, the issue is solved now, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Node.replaceChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild)

```js
//Find the specific selector to get the span
var span = document.querySelector('span.foo');
var text = span.textContent;
span.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(text), span);
```

```html
<article contenteditable="true">
    alice <span class="foo">bob</span> eve <span class="foo">bob</span>"
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function a shown below:

```js
function replaceSpan(index) {
  var parentEl = document.querySelector('article');
  var targetSpan = parentEl.querySelectorAll('span')[index];
  parentEl.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(targetSpan.innerText), targetSpan);
}

/* jQuery equivalent
 function replaceSpan(index) {
   var $targetSpan = $('article').find('span:eq(' + index + ')');
   $targetSpan.replaceWith($targetSpan.text());
 }*/

replaceSpan(0)
```

```html
<!--script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script-->
<article contenteditable="true">
  alice <span class="foo">bob</span> eve <span class="foo">bob</span>"
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not necessarily the first. Please see the edited question.

Comment: @dimid instead of `:first` you can use `:eq(index)` selector

Comment: Where is the jQuery tag?

Comment: Ah.. Didn't notice that... I thought it's jquery when i saw it in my feed :)

Comment: @dimid Are you using jQuery? If not I'll remove the answer. you'll need to replace it with js equivalent

Comment: BTW, I don't have the index, but rather the element itself saved in `mySpan`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a possible way, but be carefull when using it. Also don't forget to check [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML#Browser_compatibility).

```js
var span = document.querySelector("span");
span.outerHTML = span.innerHTML;
```

```css
span { background: silver; }
```

```html
<article contenteditable="true">
    alice <span class="foo">bob</span> eve <span class="foo">bob</span>"
</article>
```

PS: I think that methods working only with dom nodes are much better then this one. In this answer html is parsed again, so there even listeners attached to nodes inside of the old elements will be dropped. Also it's possible that results of the parsing will differ from original structure.

Comment: The most elegant solution. +1. Can you just replace `span` with `mySpan` to be compatible with the question?

Comment: @dimid, I don't thing we should use the same naming. Also I don't this is the best solution as it can cause some problems.

Comment: What problems? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check browser support for all methods.

```js
~function () {
  var span = document.querySelector("span");
  var parent = span.parentElement;
  while (span.firstChild) parent.insertBefore(span.firstChild, span);
  parent.removeChild(span);
}();
```

```css
span { background: silver; }
```

```html
<article contenteditable="true">
    alice <span class="foo">b<a href="//google.ru">o</a>b</span> eve <span class="foo">bob</span>"
</article>
```

Answer (score -1):

As jQuery tag has been added to the question, here is a simple solution with jQuery:

```js
$("span").eq(0).replaceWith(function () { return $(this).contents() })
```

```css
span { background: silver; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<article contenteditable="true">
    alice <span class="foo">bob</span> eve <span class="foo">bob</span>"
</article>
```